# Getting limited data based on group by

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a hive table like

```
name        city
-----     ---------
John        CA
Bird        CA
...         ...
....        ...
Fred        MA
Don         MA
```

For each city there are hundreds of unique names.
I want to get limited random names for each city.

For example for city `CA` I would do

```
select * from table_a where city="CA" order by rand() LIMIT 10;
```

Similar for city `MA`.

I wanna write a single query which does this for all given cities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `row_number()`- window function

```
select * from
(
select * , row_number() over(partition by city order by rand()) as rn
from tablename
)A where rn<=10
```